# How can i understand login is succes or not on hidden webbrowser in c# webForms

Tags: c#, authentication

its my code i dont want to see webbrowse in my design. i try to when i click button if password is correct login is success but i cannot see what happen how can i check login is succes or not without webBrowser .
For example login is succes or not just i want to see messagebox.Thanks for help.

```
public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            webBrowser1.Navigate("http://195.2.23.56:3635/LoginPage.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fError%2fAppError.aspx");
            webBrowser1.Hide();
            webBrowser1.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                HtmlElement ele = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("KullaniciAdiTextBox");
                if (ele == null) { ele.InnerText = "username"; } else { ele.InnerText = textBox1.Text; }
                ele = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("SifreTextBox");
                if (ele == null) { ele.InnerText = "password"; } else { ele.InnerText = textBox2.Text; }
                ele = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("SistemeGirImageButton");
                if (ele != null) { ele.InvokeMember("click"); }
                webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted);


            }
            private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
            {
                string s = webBrowser1.DocumentText;
            }
```

Comment: You can check the DocumentText, i.e. if it contains "Invalid password" it failed, if it contains "Welcome back" (or whatever) it passed.

Comment: How can i check the DocumentText can you give detail?

Comment: You already have the text, just use a Contains. s.Contains("text that should be on the page if it failed");

Comment: i define string s = webBrowser1.Url.AbsoluteUri and  in private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted. i try login success or not like this if (s.IndexOf("Login") == -1) {  ......} if success its come back to main but webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted event be infinity loop how can i fix it